# Wine: Do folder-to-drive-letter association settings have the effect of a sandbox?

Tags: wine

In Wine it is possible to associate certain folders of the Linux tree with drive letters that Wine provides to the Windows programs. Now if I only have drive letter C for the `/home/myusername/.wine/drive_c` and no other associations, will this prevent Windows apps from accessing other folders outside of this one? I'd like to know this so that I can assess the risk of Win Malware messing with my files and system, whether there's the need for some kind of a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would say not.

If your computer is at risk from malware from whatever source, the structure of the file system will have little impact in preventing it.